# Parse further an expression in a special case

Tags: parsing, ocaml, frontend, lexer

At the moment my frontend can parse such normal expressions as `123`, `"abcd"`, `"=123"`, `"=TRUE+123"`... The following are related code:

```
(* in `syntax.ml`: *)
and expression =
  | E_integer of int  
  | E_string of string

(* in `parser.mly`: *)
expression:
  | INTEGER { E_integer $1 }
  | STRING { E_string $1 }
```

Now I would like to refine the parser, so that, when we meet a string starting with `=`, we try to evaluate it as a formula, not a literal string. So `syntax.ml` turns to be:

```
(* in `syntax.ml`: *)
and expression =
  | E_integer of int  
  | E_string of string
  | E_formula of formula

and formula =
  | F_integer of int  
  | F_boolean of bool
  | F_Add of formula * formula
```

The question is I am not sure how to change `parser.mly`, I tried this which did not work (`This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type Syntax.formula`):

```
(* in `parser.mly`: *)
expression:
  | INTEGER { E_integer $1 }
  | STRING { 
    if String.sub $1 1 1 <> "="
    then E_string $1
    else E_formula (String.sub $1 2 ((String.length $1) - 1)) }
```

I don't know how to let the parser know, for a string beginning with `=`, I need to parse it further based on the rules for `formula`... Could anyone help?

**Following the comment of `gasche`:**

I agree that I need to have a parser for formula. Now the question is if I need a separate `lexer.mll` for formula. I hope not, because it is logic to lex the whole program only one time, no? Also, can I add directly the formula grammar to the existing `parser.mly`?

In the current `lexer.mll`, I have:

```
let STRING = double_quote ([^ '\x0D' '\x0A' '\x22'])* double_quote
rule token = parse
  | STRING as s { STRING s }
```

I think i can directly do something here:

```
let STRING = double_quote ([^ '\x0D' '\x0A' '\x22'])* double_quote    
let FORMULA_STRING = double_quote = ([^ '\x0D' '\x0A' '\x22'])* double_quote
rule token = parse
  | FORMULA_STRING as fs { XXXXX }
  | STRING as s { STRING s }
```

I am not sure what I should write at the place of `XXXXX`, should it be `Parser_formula.formula token fs`, in the case that I have separately `parser_formula.mly`? What if I have only `parser.mly` which contains all the grammars including the one of formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your line

```
    else E_formula (String.sub $1 2 ((String.length $1) - 1))
```

Instead of `(String.sub ...)`, which has type `string`, you should return a value of type `Syntax.formula`. If you had a `parse_formula : string -> Syntax.formula` function you could here write

```
    else E_formula (parse_formula (String.sub $1 2 ((String.length $1) - 1)))
```

I think you could define such a function by defining the formula grammar as a separate parser first.

**Edit:** following you own edit:

- if you go the route of calling a different parser for formulas, you don't need to define a different lexer
- if you choose to handle the distinction between strings and formulas at the lexer level (are you sure that's correct? what about real string that would begin with '='?), then you don't need to have a separate parser for formulas, you can have them as rules in your current grammar. But to do that you need your lexer to behave in a more fine-grained ways on formulas: instead of just recognizing `"=.*"` as a single token, you should recognize `"=` as a beginning-of-formula, and *lex* the rest of the formula until you encounter the closing `"`. To avoid conflicts you may want to handle simple strings with a lexing rule rather than a simple regexp as well.

If you can get the second approach to work, I think it is indeed a simpler idea.

PS: please use menhir variable naming facilities instead of `$1` as soon as the variables are not consecutive (because of intermediary terminals) or you need to repeat it more than once.

Comment: I take the second approach, at the moment I just consider all the strings beginning with "=" a formula... thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on @gasche 's answer.

You want to include new syntactic rules in your *parser*, which means that you need to change the grammar rules in *parser.mly* to accomodate these new rules.

The `String.sub` approach is somewhat in the right direction, but you are actually doing by hand what the mly file could let you automate.

Consider your `formula` type: the `F_Add` datatype there let you encode a binary sum formula,  thus containing 2 formulas.
In the mly file, you could describe it as:

```
formula:
   INTEGER                              { F_Integer $1 }
  | BOOL                                   { F_Bool $1 }
  | formula PLUS formula   { F_Add ($1, $3) }
;
```

Note how the grammar rule definition mirrors the `formula` type definition.
As you can see, the recursive property of formulas is nicely handled by the grammar rule for you.

Concerning `lexer.mll`, the regular expressions `STRING` and `FORMULA_STRING` are exactly the same. If you use them both in the same lexer rule  (as in your code snippet), it will not work as you expect it to. The lexer has no knowledge of what is going on in the parser, it **cannot choose** to provide a `STRING` or a `FORMULA_STRING` when it's convenient for the parser to fill a specific rule in. With ocamlyacc (and with the tools it drew inspiration from), it works the other way round: the parser receives tokens which the lexer has recognized from the text stream, and tries to find the rule which correspond to them, according to what he has already figured out before.

Note that the `BOOL` terminal must be regonized by _lexer.mll`(just like`INTEGER`), so you will need to amend it with the proper regular expression.

Also, you should ask yourself the following questions: 
in the `=5` formula, isn't there somewhere an expression waiting to be discovered?

If so, could you reformulate the definition of a formula in terms of expressions and new tokens?

Comment: 5 is considered as an `expression`; while `"=5"` is considered as a `formula`.